# how to show products json in api

Tags: php, api, magento, magento2

I am stuck to a problem, I am unable to get the products json in magento2? Can any one solve my problem, I get the token successfully but unable to get the products json in php

Here is my following php code

```
<?php     
$userData = ["username" => "admin", "password" => "admin_password"];

    $ch = curl_init("https://www.experian-ccmp.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

    $token = curl_exec($ch);

    $ch = curl_init("https://www.experian-ccmp.com/rest/V1/products");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); //  method
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($emailcontent));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
    die;
    $result = json_decode($result, 1);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
?>
```

here is what I get the response in json, field name is required

```
{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"product"},"trace":"#0 \/home2\/bhagnani\/public_html\/experian-ccmp\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Webapi\/ServiceInputProcessor.php(131): Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor->processInputError(Array)\n#1 \/home2\/bhagnani\/public_html\/experian-ccmp\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/InputParamsResolver.php(101): Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor->process('Magento\\\\Catalog...', 'save', Array)\n#2 \/home2\/bhagnani\/public_html\/experian-ccmp\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest.php(299): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver->resolve()\n#3 \/home2\/bhagnani\/public_html\/experian-ccmp\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest.php(216): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#4 \/home2\/bhagnani\/public_html\/experian-ccmp\/var\/generation\/Magento\/Webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#5 \/home2\/bhagnani\/public_html\/experian-ccmp\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#6 \/home2\/bhagnani\/public_html\/experian-ccmp\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#7 \/home2\/bhagnani\/public_html\/experian-ccmp\/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n#8 {main}"}
```

Thanks for the comments in advance

Comment: I have no idea about the API but I guess you should try sending a `fieldName` parameter as post data maybe. You should have an API documentation what paremerts are exptected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
$ch = curl_init("https://www.experian-ccmp.com/rest/V1/products");

Try this to get all product list

$ch = curl_init("https://www.experian-ccmp.com/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria=");

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your URL are ok.

Only change:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://www.experian-ccmp.com/rest/V1/products");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); //  method
```

to: 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "**GET**"); //  method

Check: http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/